# Remove tags in field on form submit in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to perform `strip_tags` on a field called `description` before data is saved in the database during form submission. I thought of creating a custom rule and doing it over there:

```
    'description' => array(

            'stripTags' =>array(
                    'rule' => array('StripTags'),
                    'message' => ''
            ),
    ),


public function StripTags($user = array()) {

        return !empty($user['description'])?strip_tags($user['description']):"";
    }
```

However this doesn't work since cakephp expects true/false to be returned instead of an updated value. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Model::beforeSave()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave) callback, that's were all automatic pre-save data modification logic should go. It is invoked before save, but after validation.

Untested example:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array())
{
    if(!parent::beforeSave($options))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['description']))
    {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['description'] = strip_tags($this->data[$this->alias]['description']);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I changed it to `$this->data['User']['description'] = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', strip_tags($this->data['User']['description'])));` to remove empty lines as well.